# Share 3gp video files as mpeg

Tags: video

Is there a relatively easy way to convert 3gp files to share as mpeg format from an Android device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, probably not easily. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293797/3gp-to-wav-file-android/1294480#1294480) points to using [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) via the command line. It offers examples on [Audio and Video conversion](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC19). For example:

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/a.3gp /tmp/a.mp3
```

This [Android Shell Command](http://www.appbrain.com/app/android-shell-command/org.loopbot.androidshellemulator) app is on the market, which could theoretically call FFmpeg, but it looks sketchy weighing in at only 2.5 stars. Could be worth a try but it's tough to tell.